# How to import an XML feed with UTF-8 characters?

Tags: php, xml, unicode, utf-8

Here is an example of UTF-8 characters in a LastFM API XML response:

```
<artist>Psy</artist>
<name>강남스타일</name>
<album>Gangnam Style (강남스타일)</album>
```

I'm using DOMDocument::load to load the XML:

```
$doc->load('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&[parameters]')
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('track') as $node) {
'name' => $node->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue,
etc...
```

This is the result:

```
[artist] => Psy
[name] => ê°•ë‚¨ìŠ¤íƒ€ì¼
[album] => Gangnam Style (ê°•ë‚¨ìŠ¤íƒ€ì¼)
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Do you [specify encoding](http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.construct.php) on `DOMDocument` instance creation explicitly? It is required.

Comment: I originally used "$doc = new DOMDocument();" as per the tutorial I was following, but have changed it to "$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');" with no apparent result.

Comment: Are you sure that is not a printing problem? Where do you check the result?

Comment: OK, I was printing using <pre> and now that I've stripped that out, it looks more promising. I've also added UTF-8 encoding to the header().

Comment: Do not blame DOM then. Try to build correct HTML with meta and everything.